# Can I handle different multi-tenancy with a global filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, multi-tenant, action-filter

I have an asp.net mvc app which has membership implemented.
So a user has to log in. Each user belongs to a organisation (multi-tenancy).

How would I handle the organisation parameter globaly? I was thinking this could be a good thing for a global filter because all the data needs to be filtered for the given organisation. And the organisation is connected with the username but not in the same table.

for example I have a index action like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
var result = _repository.GetListByOrganisation(organisation);
return View(result);
}
```

I was thinking about having a global attribute thats queries the db for an organisation based on a giving username. Since my controller already contains the authorize attribute I have the user name. It would be nice to cache the organisation (session, controllercontext) and not query the organisation from db on each request.

Is this a way to implement something like this?  Or are there other ways which would be better? And how can I set a property on the controller / controllercontext from whithin a filter?

So any thoughts on this as well as comments would be great...

Comment: How are you tracking the organization parameter on the client? Cookie, custom header, URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this via DI.

You can use either a third-party DI container or your own code. Either way, you want to set the organization ID on a *per-request* basis.

So you'll be creating a unit of work and injecting that in your controller. For the sake of simplicity, let's pretend that your unit of work is the `_repository` field in your sample code, even though most real-world apps are more complex.

You add a constructor parameter to the controller:

```
public FooController(IFooRepository repository)
{
    this._repository = repository;
}
```

...and an organization ID on `FooRepository`:

```
public class FooRepository: IFooRepository
{
    public FooRepository(long organizationId)
    {
        this._organizationId = organizationId;
    }
}
```

Now in either your DI container setup or a MVC controller factory, you set this all up:

```
builder.Register(c => new FooRepository(GetOrgIdForCurrentUser()).As<IFooRepository>();
builder.Register(c => new FooController(c.Resolve<IFooRepository>());
```

Comment: Yes, I already inject my repository. But I have a user store database and a business db. Now I have logged in user and I want to retrieve the organisation form other db. And I thought about doing this with a filter since I need it in almost every controller action...

Comment: Once again: I would use a controller factory or DI container rather than a filter to do this, because that's the right place for constructor injection. This covers all controllers, but, unlike the filter, runs *before* the controller is constructed.

Comment: I think this makese sence since you are already injecting your repository.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could have the organization embedded on the URL, for example if your route looks like this /{organization}/{controller}/{action}

then you'll get URLs like

- /bigorg/products/list
- /smallorg/products/list

and you'll receive the organization in your controller either a parameter to your method or via the RouteData object.